Error when trying to log in to NEXT 14 with AWS amplify + NextAuth + Firebase
I am performing a migration from ECR to AWS Amplify, at the time of implementing the app everything is going well but when I try to log in I have 500 errors such as:
api/auth/_log:1
   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()

api/auth/session:1
   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()

_app-75ef2dd2d601f092.js:161 [next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error There is a problem with the server configuration. Check the server logs for more information. Object
This is my [...nextauth].ts
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword, getIdToken } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "@/lib/firebase-config";
import { converterJwtToSessionData, parseJwt } from "@/utils/jwt.utils";
import { ITokenPayload } from "@/types/user-session";

// @ts-ignore
async function refreshAccessToken(token) {
  try {
    console.log("[NextAuth] Refreshing access token for token:", token);
    const user = auth.currentUser;
    if (user) {
      const newAccessToken = await user.getIdToken(true);
      console.log("[NextAuth] Successfully refreshed access token:", newAccessToken);
      return {
        ...token,
        accessToken: newAccessToken,
        accessTokenExpires: Date.now() + 3600 * 1000, 
        refreshToken: token.refreshToken,
      };
    }
    throw new Error("No user found");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("[NextAuth] Error refreshing access token:", error);

    return {
      ...token,
      error: "RefreshAccessTokenError",
    };
  }
}

export const authOptions = {
  pages: {
    signIn: "/signin",
    newUser: "/licenses",
  },
  cookies: {
    sessionToken: {
      name: `__Secure-next-auth.session-token`,
      options: {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'None' as 'none', 
        path: '/',
        secure: true
      }
    },
    callbackUrl: {
      name: `__Secure-next-auth.callback-url`,
      options: {
        sameSite: false,
        path: '/',
        secure: true
      }
    },
    csrfToken: {
      name: `__Host-next-auth.csrf-token`,
      options: {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: false,
        path: '/',
        secure: true
      }
    },
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "credentials",
      credentials: {},
      async authorize(credentials): Promise<any> {
        console.log("[NextAuth] Incoming credentials:", credentials);

        return await signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          auth,
          (credentials as any).email || "",
          (credentials as any).password || ""
        )
        .then((userCredential) => {
          console.log("[NextAuth] Firebase signInWithEmailAndPassword successful:", userCredential.user);
          return userCredential.user ? userCredential.user : userCredential;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          const errorCode = error.code;
          const errorMessage = error.message;
          console.log("[NextAuth] Authentication ERROR:", { errorCode, errorMessage });
        });
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    // @ts-ignore
    async jwt({ token, user, account }) {
      console.log("[NextAuth] JWT callback - existing token:", token);
      if (user) {
        console.log("[NextAuth] New user detected, generating token for user:", user);
        const accessToken = await user.getIdToken();
        console.log("[NextAuth] Generated new access token:", accessToken);

        return {
          accessToken,
          accessTokenExpires: Date.now() + 3600 * 1000,
          refreshToken: user.stsTokenManager.refreshToken,
          uid: user.uid,
          email: user.email,
        };
      }

      if (Date.now() < token.accessTokenExpires) {
        console.log("[NextAuth] Token still valid, returning existing token.");
        return token;
      }

      console.log("[NextAuth] Token expired, refreshing access token.");
      return refreshAccessToken(token);
    },
    // @ts-ignore
    async session({ session, token }) {
      console.log("[NextAuth] Session callback - incoming session:", session);
      console.log("[NextAuth] Session callback - incoming token:", token);

      const payloadSession = converterJwtToSessionData(token.accessToken);

      console.log("[NextAuth] Converted JWT to session data:", payloadSession);

      session.user = payloadSession.user;
      session.token = payloadSession.token;

      const jwtPayload = payloadSession.token;
      const jwtExpirationTime = jwtPayload.exp * 1000;
      const jwtTimeLife = jwtExpirationTime - Date.now();
      const jwtMinTimeLifeAllowed = Number(process.env.JWT_MIN_TIME_LIFE_ALLOWED || 300000);
      const jwtTimeToRefresh = Number(process.env.JWT_TIME_TO_REFRESH || 3000);

      console.log("[NextAuth] JWT Time life:", jwtTimeLife);
      if (jwtTimeLife > jwtMinTimeLifeAllowed) {
        console.log("[NextAuth] JWT time life sufficient, returning session");
        return session;
      }

      if (jwtTimeLife <= jwtMinTimeLifeAllowed && jwtTimeLife > jwtTimeToRefresh) {
        console.log("[NextAuth] Refreshing access token");
        session.token.accessToken = await auth.currentUser?.getIdToken(true);
        return session;
      }

      console.log("[NextAuth] JWT time life too short, session invalid");
      return;
    },
  },
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);

Do I need to make any additional modifications? Or why the libraries are incompatible?
Next 13
Amplify Gen2
